# Promise ignoring simple syncronous operation

Tags: javascript

In a promise, I want to assign a value to the property of several objects created from a class (in a loop), but when executing the function and doing the `.then(() => console.log(r))` thing, the r does was not modified to what the promise promised me it would.

Here:

```
function assignSentenceImageDescription () {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        assigningWordsPartOFSpeech().then((r) => {

                JSON.parse(r).sentences.forEach((sentence) => {
                        let adjectiveBeforeNoun = [];
                        let sentenceImageDescription = [];
                        sentence.words.forEach((wordInSentence) => {
                            try {
                                if (wordInSentence.partOfSpeech[0].wordtype === "n.") {
                                    let imageDescription = adjectiveBeforeNoun.join('') + wordInSentence.partOfSpeech[0].word;
                                    sentenceImageDescription.push(imageDescription)
                                    adjectiveBeforeNoun = [];
                                } else if (wordInSentence.partOfSpeech[0].wordtype === "superl.") {
                                    adjectiveBeforeNoun.push(wordInSentence.partOfSpeech[0].word + " ")
                                }
                            } catch (e) {
                                console.log("===NOT IN DICTIONARY===")
                            }
                        })
                        sentence.imageDescription = sentenceImageDescription;
                    }
                )
                resolve(r);
            }
        );
    }
    );
}
```

On the line

```
sentence.imageDescription = sentenceImageDescription;
```

I try to assign the image description of each of the sentences iterated over, but when I do

```
assignSentenceImageDescription().then(r => console.log(r));
```

the `r` object still does not have each of its `sentences`'s imageDescription property modified to the value the array `sentenceImageDescription` has, which is what the `assignSentenceImageDescription()` function is intended to do.

Comment: since `assigningWordsPartOFSpeech()` already returns a Promise, wrapping it in a Promise constructor is an anti-pattern - you're also `resolve(r);` ... which means the function `assignSentenceImageDescription` returns a Promise that resolves to the original JSON, so nothing you've done effects that JSON string

Comment: @Bravo in that function, if I make it syncronous without having .then() functionality (and instead of resolve I return r), then I get undefined. any suggestion?

Comment: `if I make it syncronous` you can't make asynchronous function synchronous

Comment: @Bravo any suggestions? plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor your code as follows:

Note: you don't need a Promise constructor since `assigningWordsPartOFSpeech` returns a Promise that you can work with (and return)

Set `sentences = JSON.parse(r).sentences;`

Now you can iterate through sentences as you already do, then simply `return sentences` in the `.then` - and you're done

```
function assignSentenceImageDescription() {
    return assigningWordsPartOFSpeech().then((r) => {
        const data = JSON.parse(r);
        data.sentences.forEach((sentence) => {
            let adjectiveBeforeNoun = [];
            let sentenceImageDescription = [];
            sentence.words.forEach((wordInSentence) => {
                try {
                    if (wordInSentence.partOfSpeech[0].wordtype === "n.") {
                        let imageDescription = adjectiveBeforeNoun.join('') + wordInSentence.partOfSpeech[0].word;
                        sentenceImageDescription.push(imageDescription)
                        adjectiveBeforeNoun = [];
                    } else if (wordInSentence.partOfSpeech[0].wordtype === "superl.") {
                        adjectiveBeforeNoun.push(wordInSentence.partOfSpeech[0].word + " ")
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log("===NOT IN DICTIONARY===")
                }
            })
            sentence.imageDescription = sentenceImageDescription;
        });
        return data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the time, however the "r" object contain more stuff and I want the modified sentence objects to still be part of the one "r" object. If I return just the sentences then I only get an object with just the sentences. I could embed it afterwards but that would be very spaggeti.

Comment: `r` is not an object, it is a string

Comment: @XaviFont - I've modified the code so that `data` is now the parsed JSON - i.e. `data` is a plain ol' javascript Object - now you can use `data.sentences.forEach` to do what you've shown in your question ... and anything else you want to do with the response can be done on the `data` variable, which is what you can return at the end of that .then - I apologise for answering the code in the question, rather than some other code you haven't even shown

Comment: Great!!! It works. Thanks for the explanation too. check this out https://i.redd.it/thnmrz6us7491.png